# Mi Band problem

Tags: xiaomi, fitness

My Xiaomi Mi Band keeps doing following steps repeatedly:
1. Show one green light
2. Show two green lights and one red light
3. Show three white lights
4. Vibrate

My phone doesn't see it at the moment and when I put to charge it shows one green light, then three green lights and then nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.